# Strange behaviour of a Socket attribute in a Moose Object

Tags: perl, sockets, moose

I have a Moose Object which has a IO::Socket::INET object as one of its attributes:

```
has socket => (
    is => 'ro',
    required => 1,
    lazy => 1,
    isa => 'IO::Socket::INET',
    builder => 'connect',
);
```

The socket is initialized in a script that looks like this (the authentication part is removed):

```
sub connect {
    my $self = shift;
    my $host = 'A.B.C.D';
    my $port = N;

    my $handle = IO::Socket::INET->new(
        Proto     => "tcp",
        PeerAddr  => $host,
        PeerPort  => $port
    ) or die "can't connect to port $port on $host: $!";

    $handle->autoflush(1);

   # Connect to Server with $handle and authenticate
   # and if successful .......
    return $handle;
}
```

However I find strange behaviour when I run the following test code:

```
my $x = MyObject->new;
print $x->socket pack('I', 392);
```

The bytes received by the Server (A.B.C.D) are completely different from the ones I sent. I have checked that endian-ness or byte order is not an issue. *In fact a simple script that creates a socket and writes the same data without using Moose works perfectly - the data is received at the server exactly as expected*.

Do I have to do something more than what I am doing if my Moose attribute is a persistent IO::Socket::INET object. Is the socket attribute being closed or otherwise manipulated behind my back?

Thank you.

Comment: fyi, `$handle->autoflush(1);` is already done for you.

Comment: There was a bug in my authentication code that left a few more bytes than the server expected - which got read with the nextr read on the server.  Sorry for wasting the time of the great guys here.

Answer (score 4):

The `print` documentation says that you should enclose anything more complicated than a scalar variable for the FILEHANDLE in a block. Have you tried:

```
print { $x->socket } pack ('I', 392);
```

Or:

```
$x->socket->print (pack ('I', 392));
```

I get a syntax error if I don't put braces around `$x->socket`.

The following code works for me. Are you sure something isn't going wrong in the authentication section? Maybe look at the socket data with wireshark?

```
package Test;
use Moose;
use IO::Socket::INET;

has socket => (
    is => 'ro',
    required => 1,
    lazy => 1,
    isa => 'IO::Socket::INET',
    builder => 'connect',
);

sub connect {
        my $sock = IO::Socket::INET->new (
                Proto => "tcp",
                PeerAddr => "127.0.0.1",
                PeerPort => 2000,
        ) or die;
        $sock;
}

package main;

my $x = Test->new;
print { $x->socket } pack ('I', 392);
```

Comment: I did. I also tried $x->socket->syswrite(pack('I', 392), 4) too. No Joy :(

Comment: There was indeed a bug in my authentication code. Sincere apologies for wasting your time and thank you for your patience

Answer (score 3):

I cannot reproduce your problem.

I used

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use IO::Socket::INET;
use Moose;

has socket => (
    is => 'ro',
    required => 1,
    lazy => 1,
    isa => 'IO::Socket::INET',
    builder => 'connect',
);

sub connect {
    my $self = shift;
    my $host = 'localhost';
    my $port = 12345;

    my $handle = IO::Socket::INET->new(
        Proto     => "tcp",
        PeerAddr  => $host,
        PeerPort  => $port
    ) or die "can't connect to port $port on $host: $!";

   # Connect to Server with $handle and authenticate
   # and if successful .......
    return $handle;
}

my $x = __PACKAGE__->new;
print { $x->socket } pack('I', 392);
```

And I got

```
$ nc -l -p 12345 | od -t x1
0000000 88 01 00 00
0000004
```

What do you get? What did `print` return?

Comment: Ran with nc -l 12345 and it prints the correct result. But run nc on the server and it prints junk.

Comment: @Gurunandan, That you're getting something means you are correctly getting the socket from the object, and that this has nothing to do with Moose. And now you say it even works fine for localhost. Time to look elsewhere!

Comment: Right! My authentication code left a few bytes more than the server expected, which got appended to the next read. Sincere apologies for wasting your time. Considering that I discovered nc, it was not a waste really. Thanks!